# Wave Analitycs Bar Chart

Tags: dashboard, analytics, einstein-analytics

I'm pretty new with wave analitycs, but the users of our Org have some requirments on this product. Below I show one of our dashboard on invoice:

[image]

The first requirement is that they want to view a bar that is the sum on the other bars, but with analytics I'm not able to do so then I want to know if some workaround exists
The second requirement is that they want to change the dashboard's labels to something more meaningful but the customizations available that I can do on the lens don't let me change the label so how can I do that?

Comment: Try to add the step in Wave and then change the Chart type by clicking on the chart in your Dashboard, and changing it to Waterfall. This will give you a sum of your total. Otherwise you might have to add in a formula field that can roll up your data.

Answer (score 0):

As @Geo commented, you can get a summation bar by changing to Waterfall. First, though, clip the lens to the Wave dashboard builder. Once you've got in the builder and display it as waterfall, you'll be able to customize some of the labels.